# Confused by SyntaxNode.ReplaceNodes<>()

Tags: c#, immutability, roslyn

I'm trying to replace an InvocationExpressionSyntax node with my own constructed InvocationExpressionSyntax node.

The only way I've found so far is using SyntaxNode.ReplaceNodes<>,  but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how it works.

Here's a code snip

```
public override SyntaxNode VisitInvocationExpression(InvocationExpressionSyntax node)
{
    InvocationExpressionSyntax replacementNode = (constructing my own invocation node, etc.

    node = (InvocationExpressionSyntax)node.ReplaceNodes(new List<InvocationExpressionSyntax>() { replacementNode /* ##Solution: This should be the EXISTING node, not the replacement node*/ }, new Func<InvocationExpressionSyntax, InvocationExpressionSyntax, SyntaxNode>((old, old2) =>
        {
            //return what?  old and old2 are both unmodified at this point. Doing another node.replacenodes in here doesn't work either. How do I replace node?
            //even the following doesn't work. 
            return replacementNode;
        }));
}
```

The metadata for the Func<> arg of the method:

> A function that computes a replacement node for the argument nodes. The first
>   argument is the original node. The second argument is the same node rewritten
>   with replaced descendants.

There's no other way to replace a node that I can find.  Even when I return the replacement node I built, it just returns the original node.

How do I simply replace an entire node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code snippet confuses me a little bit. ReplaceNodes replaces the nodes specified in the first argument, so the first argument should be a list of *existing* nodes, not new nodes. You can just create your new nodes in the lambda for the second argument, and those are substituted in the tree. If you have to know which of the nodes you're currently replacing, look at the first of the two arguments ("old" in your example) to know what it is.

Comment: Heh,  I guess I was more confused than I thought :D  That was indeed my problem.

Comment: I am still confused by what that `Func` is supposed to do with its second argument.  What does "the same node rewritten with replaced descendants" mean?  Does that mean its a copy of the first argument? How would you have a copy of the first argument with replaced nodes if you have not yet invoked `ReplaceNodes`?

Comment: Node replacement could be recursive. Consider a feature like "swap arguments" where you are rewriting method calls to swap the two arguments. If you're rewriting Call(Call(A, B), B), the inner rewrite happens, and then this will be called with a tree something like Call(Call(B, A), B). When it's called for the outer call, the "original" node will be the original start, the "rewritten" will be where the inner call has been rewritten.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the workaround alternative I found for now:

```
node = node.WithExpression(replacementNode);
```

Comment: I don't think that's a workaround, it's the proper way to do this.